# Raster merge in QGIS still displays boundaries

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, mosaic, band-interleaved-by-line

I am merging 43 raster .BIL files and while the merge function works, the boundaries between the images are still visible. I have tried different settings in the Mosaic raster layers tool and the Merge Raster tool. Some of the images are overlapping, some are not. Here are two results I received from the Mosaic and Merge tools respectively (the mosaic is not clipped). Is this an issue with the data? Some of the images are older than others. I downloaded the data from: http://en.www.inegi.org.mx/temas/relieve/continental/#Map [image: Elevation map of Tabasco, Mexico composed of 43 raster images]

[image]

Comment: You should probably first check if the raster data is contiuous to start with. How did you get the colors that you show (singleband pseudo color ?) If so, you can apply the exact same palette  forcing the min&max to be common across all tiles and visually check from there. I did that on a few .Bil files from your reference site (1:50 000 scale), and it looks like the .Bil tiles are not continuous

Comment: OK, thank you I will look at that! I'm guessing if they're not continuous then I won't be able to merge the tiles like I want to?